# Troubleshooting 'This site can’t be reached' error on AWS Elastic Beanstalk environment with CodePipeline

Tags: docker, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, github-actions, aws-codepipeline

I have a Dockerized React app that I'm deploying to AWS Elastic Beanstalk. The app is running on 64-bit Amazon Linux 2/3.5.6. I've successfully set up GitHub with AWS CodePipeline, and I am using Elastic Beanstalk for deployment. However, when I try to access the environment link that AWS has provided me, I get a “This site can’t be reached” error.

Is there anything else I can do to troubleshoot this issue?

I've checked the Elastic Beanstalk environment status in the AWS console, and everything appears to be running smoothly. I've also made sure that the security group rules allow incoming traffic on port 80. Additionally, I've reviewed the logs for the Elastic Beanstalk environment, but didn't find any errors.